# VIM: how to append yanked text to unnamed register

Tags: vim

I know `"Ayy` can append current line to register a.

How do I append current line to unnamed register?

Comment: Thanks for telling how to append to a named register. Vim newbies like me should note that the `A` to type is a capital one to append to the lower case register `a`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this

```
:let @"=@".getline('.')
```

to append to the unnamed register. I do not believe there is a keyboard shortcut to do this. (However you could create a mapping if you wanted.)

---

The reason I say that there is no keyboard shortcut for this is because `:h quote_alpha` only talks about uppercase letters (for appending). And there is no equivalent statement in `:h quote_quote`

Comment: Is there a register like register A for register a?

Comment: @xiaochen not that I know of. Why exactly do you want to append to the unnamed register?

Comment: I want a register for unnamed register just like register A (`"Ay{Motion}`) for register a.

Comment: @xiaochen Just use a named register for appending

Comment: Here's the necessary .vimrc code to map this to the Y key: `nnoremap Y :let @*=@*.getline('.')<Return>` (Note: this example uses @* instead of @" because I have configured vim to use the system clipboard with `set clipboard=unnamed`

Comment: use `:let @"=@".getline('.')."\n"` to preserve the line feed

Answer (score 4):

1. Pick a free register among a-z (I prefer the register a)
2. "ay{motion}
3. "Ay{motion} ... (to append)
4. Now you have all the yanked text in register a.
5. And you have the same content in unnamed register as well!

(I happened to find that the unnamed register is synchronized to the named register in such operation.)

The benefit is ... You saves 2 keystrokes to put. ^_^

See h: quote_quote

NB: For operations d, c, s, x, you won't get the same appended text in the unnamed register as in the named register if you are using v7.4. (It's a bug, fixed in v8.0)