# Vim: append to special registers (e.g. +)

Tags: vim

I would like to make a shortcut to append to the register "+" (so I can do a system paste outside of Vim). For example, I would like to do `"+yy` to copy one line, and then `"=yy` to append another line to the '+' register.

I've found
[VIM: how to append yanked text to unnamed register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536511/vim-how-to-append-yanked-text-to-unnamed-register)
and I feel like it should be easy to get what I want, but I don't understand anything of Vim script.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/how-to-copy-non-continuous-matched-lines-into-clipboard-td1164018.html#a1164021) will help until a real expert comes along!

Answer (score 1):

You could choose an arbitrary register, say `z`, to which you do the appending dance, `"zyy` then `"Zyy`, and create a shortcut just for "exporting" that register:

```
nnoremap <silent> <key> :<C-u>call setreg('+', getreg('z', 1), getregtype('z'))<CR>
```

(Edited as per ZyX's comment.)

Comment: Do not use `:let` for copying register contents: there is `setreg()` for this. To copy `z` to `+` you need `setreg('+', getreg('z', 1, 1), getregtype('z'))`. Reasons: 1. `:let` does not preserve register type (and yes, Vim saves register type somewhere even if you use system register) 2. `@c` converts NULs to newlines.