# Set active register persistently in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to change the active register persistently in Vim?

The `"` register is used by default, if I want to use the `a` register I have to prepend `"a` to my normal mode command. After giving the command, the active register gets switched back to `"`.

Is there a way to tell Vim to keep a specific register active until explicitly told not to do so?

Comment: No. What's wrong with the unnamed register?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why would you want to work with "a instead of standard register?

Comment: [I can't easily append content to the unnamed register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536511/vim-how-to-append-yanked-text-to-unnamed-register), while it's very easy to do so when using a named register. That's about it.

Comment: Also, sometimes I need to switch register to avoid overriding the unnamed register, and I was wondering if there was a way to just keep a named register active until further notice. Other than that, pure curiosity.

Comment: Still not sure what you want to do but if you need a specific variable saved for later use assign it to a named variable :let var=@a and then put it back when needed. When I have variables I want to save between sessions I write them to a var file

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option to achieve your goal.

You can read and change the vim source code for your requirement for sure.

It is also not easy to implement it with vimscript, what I can think of:

- declare a var, indicate the target "unnamed reg", e.g. `a`
- create mappings for `d D s S c C y Y p P ...` commands, let them call your function
- in your function, you check the variable to get the target, and finally fire a `"[targetReg]command` or call `set/getreg()`

However I don't think this is a good idea. You have to think about many corner cases to make your script work for all situations. For example, user pressed `"_dd` or `"bx`, your script should know that user has explicitly declared which register he wanted to use, and you should bypass your target var.

So just use the default unnamed reg.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just to append to `"`, these functions and mappings should work for visual and operator pending (e.g. `$`, `w`, `fx`, etc...).

```
function! AppOp(type, ...)
  call App(a:type, a:0)
endfunction

function! App(type, visual)

  let r = @"

  if a:visual
    execute "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>y"
  else
    execute "normal! `[v`]y"
  endif

  let @" = r . @"
endfunction

xnoremap <silent> <leader>a :call App(visualmode(), 1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>a :set opfunc=AppOp<cr>g@
```

Swap `y` for `d` to delete instead of yank.  Define mappings to taste.